# C++ Access struct in sourcefile

Tags: c++, struct, header-files

I've defined my `struct` in a `.h` file, and I'm trying to access it from a `.cc` file. However, I keep getting errors when compiling.

This is in my `.h`:

```
class List
{ 
 public:
   struct ListNode 
   {
     string data;
     ListNode* next;
   };
}
```

And this is in my `.cc` file: (the `.h` file **is** included)

```
struct ListNode* startPtr;

List::List(void)
{
  startPtr = new ListNode;
  startPtr = nullptr;
}
```

When trying to use it like this,

```
void Print()
 { 
 while (startPtr) 
  { 
    cout << startPtr->data << endl;
    startPtr = startPtr->next; 
  }
 }
```

I get errors like

```
Forward declaration and unauthorized usage of undefined type.
```

Comment: Plenty of answers, but on another issue, having a global variable called startPtr is completely wrong. List should be a self contained class, it shouldn't rely on any global variables. Both your Print methods and your List constructor look wrong too.

Answer (score 3):

You must `include` the `.h` file in your `.cc` file AND as `ListNode` is defined inside `class List`, if you want to access it from outside the class (outside its definition & its methods), you *need* to specify the scope like this `List::ListNode`.

Note, that if `class List` is defined inside a specific namespace, for example `my_namespace`, if you want to access `ListNode` from the global namespace, you *need* to specify this, too. Like: `my_namespace::List::ListNode`.

Comment: You must use `List::ListNode` in the global variable declaration. It's not necessary to use `List::ListNode` in the `List` constructor, or any other `List` method.

Comment: Yes, of course. I thought about mentioning that, but I didn't, as this also needs one more "specification" - "global namespace" - what if `class List` is not in the global namespace? I know what you mean, I'll add this into my answer, just noticing.

Answer (score 0):

Your list node class is inner class. It's type is: `List::ListNode` not just `ListNode` like you use it.

Also as you mention forward declaration(though I don't see any in this code): you will not be able to forward declare an inner class.

Answer (score 0):

You made `ListNode` a nested type of `List`, so you have to refer to it as `List::ListNode`. You can leave off the `struct` when you declare `startPtr` though.

Of course, since `List::ListNode` is redundant, you might want to rename it to just `Node`.

Answer (score 0):

- include the .h file in your .cc file
- refer to structure as `List::ListNode` as it is a nested type
- don't have to write `struct ListNode* startPtr;` just `List::ListNode* startPtr;`
- insert semicolon after class `List` definition in .h file

Answer (score 0):

Let me rephrase the answer of Kiril Kirov.
You have 2 types in your program:
- ListNode defined in the scope of the class List
- ListNode defined in global scope
The 2nd one is defined using forward declaration, without actual description of its content. That's your compiler trying to say to you.
To fix the error you need to refer correct ListNode type, when defining startPtr, e.g. you should write:

```
List::ListNode* startPtr;
```

instead of

```
struct ListNode* startPtr;
```